# How to solve C2054 in C

Tags: c

I currently using microsoft visual studio to develop a C program . I face this problem while building the header file and i google it several way but it dont fix it.

This is the header file

```
            #pragma
            #ifndef DATA_H
            #define DATA_H

            namespace
            {
                //defailt court number
                int _badminton_court, squash_court, tennis_court, futsal_court;
                //default court label
                char a = 'A', b = 'B', c = 'C', d = 'D';
            }
            #endif
```

after modify

```
            #pragma once
            #ifndef DATA_H
            #define DATA_H


                //defailt court number
                extern int _badminton_court, squash_court, tennis_court, futsal_court;
                //default court label
                extern char a = 'A', b = 'B', c = 'C', d = 'D';

            #endif
```

and the error will become 
Error (changed) :

```
Error   10  error LNK2005: _badminton_court already defined in Booking.obj  C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\Assignment\ckah\Assignment_C\Assignment_C\CourtAva.obj        Assignment_C
Error   6   error LNK2005: _a already defined in Booking.obj    C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\Assignment\ckah\Assignment_C\Assignment_C\CourtAva.obj    Assignment_C
Error   14  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\ASUS\Dropbox\Assignment\ckah\Assignment_C\Debug\Assignment_C.exe   1   1   Assignment_C
```

Error :

```
Error   1   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'namespace' c:\users\asus\dropbox\assignment\ckah\assignment_c\assignment_c\data.h  6   1   Assignment_C
Error   4   error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'namespace' c:\users\asus\dropbox\assignment\ckah\assignment_c\assignment_c\data.h  6   1   Assignment_C
```

well, i design it liek this coz i have few .c file that only method that going to access the same variable.

Comment: don't you need to give a name to your namespace?

Comment: There are no namespaces in C. Your compiler thins you are writing a method named "namespace" and it is looking for the paren(s).

Comment: Sidenote: You should only put variable *declarations* to header file (like `extern int tennis_court;`). *Definitions* should go to .c files (like `int tennis_court = 2;`).

Comment: Don't declare, let alone initialize variables in header files... just don't. That, and the errors are pretty self explanatory: you still have `namespace`'d code lying around somewhere, C doesn't do namespaces...

Answer (score 3):

There are no `namespace`s in the C++ sense in C.

Maybe you want to write a C++ program?

Comment: Well, due to some restriction , i have to do it in C , anyway to solve like change the namespace or other method ?

Comment: @user3122881 Then solution is to remove the `namespace { }`.

Comment: @user694733 i try remove it and it say the variab had already defined in my other .c file.

Comment: @user3122881 Then define them at only one place, as it is supposed to be. Except - if you need them to be separate from each other, then make them `static`.

Comment: @user3122881 See my sidenote in your question comments.

Comment: @user694733 and glglgl thanks for helps from both of you . i can carry my work go on again.